# Pure SQL Query in Rails to get customers in last 30 days

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, shopify

I would normally just use:

```
ShopifyAPI::Customer.where("created_at > ?", 30.days.ago).count
```

But I am getting this error

> ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 0..1)

So I am trying to write a pure SQL query:

```
ShopifyAPI::Customer.where("created_at > DATEADD(day, -30, getdate())").count
```

But getting this error:

> ArgumentError: expected a clauses Hash, got "created_at > DATEADD(day,
>   -30, getdate())"

Any ideas on how to get the customer count from last 30 days?

Comment: What is the underlying database?  Please tag the question with it.

Comment: Sorry about that - psql

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres, the `where` clause would look like:

```
ShopifyAPI::Customer.where("created_at > CURRENT_DATE - interval '30 day' ").count
```

The syntax you are using is SQL Server syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Just edit your first code like:

```
ShopifyAPI::Customer.where(["created_at > ?", 30.days.ago]).count
```